Local network usage description pop up is not showing ios 17.4.1
I am using google chrome cast and Airplay service to stream video.
Initial everything was working. I can see device list and able to cast or airplay videos.
Now after updating iOS 17.4.1 no pop local network usage description pop is coming. So user is not able to give permission. That's why cast and airplay is not working
In Plist I mentioned everting
1- Bonjour service
2- Local network usage description
but don't know why it stopped working.


Please let me know if anyone else face the same issue?

We have same problem here, did you fix it?

yes I resolved it. Problem was with google cast Id keep changing it until it worked.
